# How to design a class with different sub structures

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance

I have a class "Weapon" which has different behavior depending on its classification. The behavior can be changed at runtime, and the behavior can be replaced with others. (For those who know, I am describing a weapon of Worms: Armageddon).

Normally I would create different sub classes of "Weapon" which implement the specific behavior, but since it can be changed at runtime, I can't use such a "static typification".

I thought of a class weapon like the following (C#).

```
public class Weapon
{
    public AirstrikeSettings _airstrikeSettings;
    public MineSettings _mineSettings;
    public LauncherSettings _launcherSettings,
}
```

The *Settings classes contain the parameters which define the exact behavior.

At runtime, it must be checked which of the 3 setting instances is not null, to find out what classification of weapon this is. If the classification is changed, for example from Mine to Airstrike, MineSettings are set to null and AirstrikeSettings are initialized.

Is that a correct way to design this case or do I have extreme design problems?

PS: If you are interested, this is the structure I want to reflect in my class: http://worms2d.info/Project_X/Weapon_file_block

Comment: You have already listed *inheritance* among the tags, and as the structures you describe do not feature any inheritance, I suppose you already have a hunch that inheritance would be a worthwhile way to go here. Is there anything that prevents you from deriving `AirstrikeSettings`, `MineSettings` and `LauncherSettings` from `Weapon` rather than storing an instance of any one of them within `Weapon` instnces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already said, an inheritance based approach on the level of the `Weapon` will not allow you to change the behavior at runtime. 
I'd suggest to have a look at the **[Strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_design_pattern)**. It allows you to change the behavior of a class at runtime and you can avoid having lots of if-statements in the class itself.

So in your sample  the `Weapon` class would be the context and the settings the Strategy. Instead of having three separate members for each type of settings, you'd have only one member for the current settings. If you make sure that this is always set, you don't have to check against null and you always call the current setting if you want to execute setting-specific behavior. In order for this to work, the settings need to be based upon a common structure.

In order to be able to set the behavior from the outside, you create a property for the current setting that is accessible from the outside of the class and thus allows a caller to change the setting at runtime.

So your sample would look similar to this:

```
// base strategy, can also be an abstract class if you want to share 
logic between the settings
public interface IWeaponSettings 
{
    // Definition of common structure for the behaviors
    void BehaveInSpecialWay();
    // ...
}

public class AirstrikeSettings: IWeaponSettings
{
    // Implementation for Airstrike
    public void BehaveInSpecialWay()
    {
        // Airstrike
    }
}

public class MineSettings : IWeaponSettings
{
    // Implementation for Mining
    public void BehaveInSpecialWay()
    {
        // Mining
    }
}

// ...

public class Weapon
{
    // Constructor that takes the initial settings as an input
    public Weapon(IWeaponSettings settings)
    {
        Settings = settings
    }

    // Public property that can be used to change behavior. 
    // You might want to check against null in the setter
    public IWeaponSettings Settings { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Settings.BehaveInSpecialWay();
    }
}
```

Please note that if some settings do not support some behaviors, they still need to implement them, but simply do nothing or return a default value.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create an abstract `Weapon` class, and three derived classes: `AirstrikeWeapon`, `MineWeapon` and `LauncherWeapon`. Each of these subclasses can have its own settings. Then, add an `Attack` method to the base class, and implement it using whatever logic you need in each derived class. Then, at runtime, each worm has a `Weapon` member which can be set to an instance of the weapon it's currently using.

This is called polymorphism, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking simply, if I have to check `null` for knowing the type of a class at runtime, then what on earth the `Inheritance` is doing.

In your case, you can define an abstract class `Settings` which'll be the parent class of those 3 classes. Then class `Weapon` will only have the reference of class `Settings`. Please see the following code:

```
public abstract class Settings
{

}

public class AirstrikeSettings : Settings
{

}

public class MineSettings : Settings
{

}

public class LauncherSettings : Settings
{

}

public class Weapon
{
    public Settings Settings { get; set; } // as this member is public, it can be declared as property
}
```